# How to send mail using both gmail and yahoo from an application in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my application in which i need to send email.It works fine with gmail.is it is possible to do the same with yahoo mail? (If from textbox has @gmail.com it has to go to smtp.gmail.com step in controller,if from textbox has @yahoo.com it has to go to smtp.mail.yahoo.com --is it is possible?)

**my controller:**

```
 using emailtest1.Models;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    namespace emailtest1.Controllers
    {

        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Home
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(EmailModel model)
            {
                using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(model.Email, model.To))
                {
                    mm.Subject = model.Subject;
                    mm.Body = model.Body;
                    if (model.Attachment.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.Attachment.FileName);
                        mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(model.Attachment.InputStream, fileName));
                    }
                    mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
                    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(model.Email, model.Password);
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.Port = 25;
                        smtp.Send(mm);
                        ViewBag.Message = "Email sent.";
                    }
                }
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

**my model:**

```
using System.Web;
namespace emailtest1.Models
{
        public class EmailModel
        {
            public string To { get; set; }
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Body { get; set; }
            public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }
}
```

**my view:**

```
@model emailtest1.Models.EmailModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        table th, table td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 80px">
                        To:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.To)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Subject:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        Body:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { rows = "3", cols = "20" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        File Attachment:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attachment, new { type = "file" })

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Gmail:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "my_custom_id" } })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Gmail Password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Password)*@
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { type = "password" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <span style="color:green">@ViewBag.Message</span>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To clarify, is the issue with sending email with yahoo, or is the issue "how do I do both"? And if so, have you tried an if/else condition for the statement you wrote? (`If from textbox has @gmail.com it has to go to smtp.gmail.com step in controller,if from textbox has @yahoo.com it has to go to smtp.mail.yahoo.com`)?

Comment: @ashwanth can you solve the topic ?

Comment: yep i got the solution  @GGO thanks

Comment: So you can solve the topic please (checking the green tick) ? the answer that helped you the most

Answer (score 6):

You can't override Host and Port property one after the other. You have to put a condition :

```
if(model.Email.contains("@gmail.com")){
     smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
     smtp.Port = 587;
} else if(model.Email.contains("@yahoo.fr")) {
     smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
     smtp.Port = 587;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes but not like the way you did it , when you're doing :

```
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
```

You're overwriting the SMTP .

What you could do is this

```
    smtp.Port = 587;
    if (textbox.value.contains("@gmail.com"))
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    ELSE (textbox.value.contains("@yahoo.com"))
             smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
```

After that do the work...